# Заменить подстроки из таблицы

Tags: mysql, replace

Есть таблица `ForgeRock`, которая содержит поле `name`. В поле `ForgeRock.name`, необходимо выполнить замену подстроки из `ReplaceData.cut`  на данные из поля `ReplaceData.paste`

```
CREATE TABLE ForgeRock
    (`id` int, 
     `name` varchar(77), 
     `description` varchar(55)
    );

INSERT INTO ForgeRock
    (`id`,  `name`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 'OpenIDM', 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning for solutions'),
    (2, 'OpenAM', 'Full-featured access management'),
    (3, 'OpenDJ', 'Robust LDAP server for Java');



CREATE TABLE ReplaceData
    (`id` int, 
     `fieldNaame` varchar(77), 
     `f2` varchar(55), 
     `f2` varchar(55) 
    );

INSERT INTO ReplaceData
    (`id`, `cut`, `paste`)
VALUES
    (1,,'Open', 'Close'),
    (2,'IDM', 'xxxxx');
```

После отработки "нашей" замены, должно получится примерно такое

> ```
> (1, 'Closexxxxx', 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning for solutions'),
> (2, 'CloseAM', 'Full-featured access management'),
> (3, 'CloseDJ', 'Robust LDAP server for Java');
> ```

---

Первое, что приходит на ум:

```
UPDATE `ForgeRock` d, `ReplaceData` t 
SET d.`name` = replace(d.`name`, t.`cut`, t.`paste`)
```

Второе:

```
UPDATE `ForgeRock` d, `ReplaceData` t 
SET d.`name` = replace(d.`name`, t.`cut`, t.`paste`)
where  d.`name` LIKE CONCAT('%', t.`cut` ,'%');
```

Дальше не знаю.

Comment: Так а в чём проблема? Первый запрос вроде должен выполнить то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @Ksenia , он меняет только данные находящиеся в первой строке таблицы  `ReplaceData`т. е. только Open на Close

Comment: В рамках одного запроса задача не решается. Пишите ХП - prepared statement с параметрами, курсор по ReplaceData, поштучная замена.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запрос из разряда магии переменных:

```
update `ForgeRock` u
  join (
   select name, new
     from (
       select d.*,
              @cur:=if(@grp=d.name,@cur,d.name),
              @cur:=replace(@cur, t.`cut`, t.`paste`) new,
              @n:=if(@grp=d.name,@n+1,1) N,
              @grp:=d.name
         from `ForgeRock` d, `ReplaceData` t, (select @cur:='',@grp:='',@n:=0) A
        order by d.name
     ) X
     where N=@n
  ) N
    on u.name=N.name
   set u.name=N.new
```

В подзапросе данные последовательно заменяются с каждой новой строкой. `@grp` служит для запоминания текущего обрабатываемого имени и получении нового значения для @cur (текущего состояния замененной строки) при переходе к следующему имени. `@n` нумерует записи, все замены прошли, когда номер текущей строки равен количеству строк замены. А количество строк замены остается в переменной `@n` после выполнения самого глубокого подзапроса и в внешнем запросе уже можно сравнить номер строки с максимальным (`where N=@n`). Остается подклеить это к изменяемой таблице и заменить.

[Пример на sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/663c6/1)

Comment: Точно, это магия!))